# How to make one object grabable and movable at one end and the other end will be fixed on the surface in Unity VR?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

In my unity VR project, I want to execute some task with an object.

Suppose, I have one stick on the table, I want to grab only one point of the stick and the other point will be tightly attached with the table. For example: one side of the stick is tightly bind on the north point and other side(south side) that I can grab and move from south to east or west side.

Note: If I simply use grab interaction, then the entire stick comes to my hand which is not accepted. I only want to grab one certain side and other side should not be movable.

How can I perform this task?

Comment: Not sure if this works but I would probably try and go for Rigidbodies and Joints => Have your stick attached to two other bodies: Have a `CharacterJoint` (= fixed position but rotation on all axes) on the side you want to have fixed and then your invisble grabable object is attached to the stick via another one .. so basically moving your grabbable you just move around one of the anchor points and the stick follows it - you never actually interact with the stick irectly